# Организация хранения изображений в android приложении

Tags: android

В приложении предполагается организация статического перечня материалов, организованных в виде статей ("база знаний"), ~100 шт. В каждой статье содержится текст, порядка 1000 символов и 1-2 изображения (оригинальный размер, xhdpi - ~500 Kb). 
Итого получаем около 150 изображений, общим весом 75 Mb, и это только для одной плотности экрана.

Подскажите каким образом можно организовать хранение изображений для уменьшения размеров сборки? Отдельно интересуют варианты для offline приложения (предпочтительный вариант) и для приложения с загрузкой изображений через сеть после установки приложения.

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для картинок в тексте статей (тем более 1- 2 штук на страницу) можно сделать один комплект среднего качества и масштабировать под нужный размер на экране средствами системы (например параметр match_parent для ширины) - это нормальная практика.

Разделение на плотности применяется для интерфейсной графики с целью отимизации (ее обычно довольно много, а масштабирование отнимает ресурс (лаги) и память) и исключения артефактов при масштабировании (для небольших изображений увеличение/уменьшение в 2-4 раза критично). С одной картинкой справится даже бюджетное устройство, масштабирование больших картинок тоже не сильно сказывается на качесте изображения, как правило.

Оптимизировать можно (и нужно) сами картинки для уменьшения размера: формат png и [его отимизицация](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/119009/).